# How to document.querySelectAll inline css styles?

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to find all tags containing `style="filter: blur(5px);"` and remove the style so I can see what's blurry. How do I do this?

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct query for `document.querySelectorAll` to find all of these tags.

Unfortunately, this does not work.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[style=filter: blur(5px)]')
```

Edit: Thank you everyone. I was missing quotes and semicolon.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[style="filter: blur(5px);"]').forEach((tag) => { tag.style = ""; })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add double quotes around the value of the attribute. `[style="filter: blur(5px);"]`

```
document.querySelectorAll('[style="filter: blur(5px);"]');
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put quotes around the value of an attribute if it contains whitespace or other special characters.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[style="filter: blur(5px)"]')
```

Note, however, that this is looking for an exact match to the entire `style` attribute. It won't match if it's `style="color: red; filter: blur(5px)"`. If you want to match if the string appears anywhere in the attribute you need to use `*=` rather than `=`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[style*="filter: blur(5px)"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to quotes, since the attribute contains a trailing semicolon, add `;` to the end of the selector string, else it won't match:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[style="filter: blur(5px);"]').length);
```

```html
<div style="filter: blur(5px);">foo</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It selects all the elements present in the DOM via `document.querySelectorAll('*')`

The NodeList generated is then iterated and using `getAttribute` we check if the style attribute exists and if exists we check if it is equal to `"filter: blur(1px)"`. If yesy we remove that element using

```
e.parentNode.removeChild(e)
```

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('*');
a.forEach((e) => {
  if (e.getAttribute('style') !== null) {
    if (e.getAttribute('style') == "filter: blur(1px)") {
      console.log(e)
      e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div style="filter: blur(1px)">a</div>
<div>d</div>
```